# How do I resolve the syntax error when using toDateString method of Javascript?

Tags: javascript, robotframework

I am using Robot Framework and need to remove the time from a date. I use Get Current Date (exclude milliseconds) and pass value to a variable. The goal is to strip the time from the date. I have a syntax error which I cannot resolve.

```
${date}=  Get Current Date  exclude_millis=true

Execute Javascript  Date.toDateString(${date})
```

> Error: JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: missing ) after argument list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The toDateString() method returns the date portion of a Date object as a human-readable string.

Syntax:

`dateObj.toDateString();`

Parameters:

This method does not take any parameters.

Return value:

A string representing the date portion of the given Date object.

Example:

```
var d = new Date();

console.log(d.toDateString());
```

Output:

`"Wed Apr 12 2017"`

Comment: `${data.toDateString()}` would be a specific example

Comment: I found using: new Date().toLocaleDateString() provided me with the correct output.